# In tableau, can you edit an individual pane?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar graph, it has two labels, a percentage and and a total. For some bars I want both, but for others I only want the total. Can I do this? Thanks

Comment: yes, but you will get more helpful responses on StackOverflow if you provide more precise questions, say a description of which fields you are using in which way, some sample data and a screen shot. Otherwise, you are asking others to do all the work for you.

Comment: Ok I aprreciate the advice. I will use a fake example as the data is confidential.  I am interested in knowing what people's favorite chips are. In the row shelf I have a dimension called "Chips". In the column shelf I have a measure called "ID number" which is measured by count distinct.  I choose the bar graph and it gives a proper bar graph. Id like to add some labels. So I do id number with count distinct and put it on the label in the marks box. This properly labels each bar with the number of people that prefer the specific chips. I also want to add a percentage label.

Comment: So I once again use the count distinct of id number and do the percentage calculated field, and put it on the label. This works properly and now the percetnage of total is labeld on each bar. Now, I only want the percentage labels for the first 5 types of chips, and not the rest of them. Is there a way I can do this? thanks